# configure/install PHPExcel on Ubuntu 12 LTS and Apache2 for Phabricator

Tags: apache, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, phpexcel, phabricator

I'm trying to install PHPExcel on my Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS - hosted by Amazon EC2).

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.pearplex.net
sudo pear install pearplex/PHPExcel
```

These seem to have installed PHPExcel here:

```
/usr/share/php/PHPExcel
```

I tried adding this include path to /etc/php5/cli/php.ini:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php/PHPExcel"
```

But the module doesn't seem to be installed? I rebooted the server, apache2, etc..

I'm afraid of killing my webserver by randomly trying stuff.

some more info:

php --ini =

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini
```

My installed php modules: (php -m)

> apc
>   bcmath
>   bz2
>   calendar
>   Core
>   ctype
>   curl
>   date
>   dba
>   dom
>   ereg
>   exif
>   fileinfo
>   filter
>   ftp
>   gd
>   gettext
>   hash
>   iconv
>   json
>   libxml
>   mbstring
>   mcrypt
>   mhash
>   mysql
>   mysqli
>   openssl
>   pcntl
>   pcre
>   PDO
>   pdo_mysql
>   Phar
>   posix
>   readline
>   Reflection
>   session
>   shmop
>   SimpleXML
>   soap
>   sockets
>   SPL
>   standard
>   sysvmsg
>   sysvsem
>   sysvshm
>   tokenizer
>   wddx
>   xml
>   xmlreader
>   xmlwriter
>   zip
>   zlib

I'm stumped, I'm not sure what to do.

This is probably super simple for someone who knows their way around php / apache2, etc., but that isn't me. I'm a developer, just not for this platform.

What do I do now?

thanks!

Comment: I doubt about gd2. Check out this. It might help you : http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Requirements&referringTitle=Features

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about gd2. I already visited that site - I don't see much help for newbies trying to install it. Though maybe I missed it?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `include_path` to `.:/usr/share/php/PHPExcel/Classes` (that is, just add "/Classes" at the end), as per the error message from Phabricator:

> Your PHP "include_path" needs to be updated to include the PHPExcel Classes/ directory.

Broadly, PHPExcel is a library (written in PHP, loaded at runtime by applications) not an extension (written in C, reported by `php -m`, loaded at startup by PHP), so it won't be reported by `php -m` and has no `.ini` file, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Phabricator install on a Linux box, and I did the following to get PHPExcel installed into my Phabricator:

1. Get a copy of PHPExcel by going to https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel and doing a "git clone https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel" or going to the green "Clone or Download" button at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel and click "Download Zip". Note the path where you cloned or unzipped to, and make sure there is a "Classes" folder inside it. For the purposes of this walk-through, I copied the PHPExcel folder into my Phabricator folder.
2. In your Linux/OSX shell, change directory or "cd" to your Phabricator installation, and type "find . -name "php.ini" to locate the php.ini associated with Phabricator. For my version, it was in $PHABRICATOR/php/etc/php.ini
3. Make a copy of your php.ini file as a backup, and then open the php.ini you found in step 2 in an editor
4. In the editor find the "include_path" statement, it should look like this ...

*include_path = ".:/root/servers/phabricator/php/lib/php"*

... and you should change it to ...

*include_path = ".:/root/servers/phabricator/php/lib/php:**/root/servers/phabricator/PHPExcel/Classes**"*

5. Restart Phabricator, by changing directory or doing a "cd" to your Phabricator root folder, and do a "./ctlscript.sh restart"

It worked for me, and hopefully also for you.